# How to hide error log from hackers?

Tags: php, error, hacking, apache-log-files

I'm a developer of self hosted web application. which creates the error log but others can access it rather than only admin of that application. is there any way to protect it from page other people like hackers?

Answer (score 2):

Place that log outside of your webroot. That way the only way to access it is through a script which can contain authentication (i.e. a password).

Comment: can i change any extensions ? or like that?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Can you elaborate on this?